# Issue With Reading A Text File Key In Same Program Instance

Tags: python, tkinter, numbers, key

The issue I am having with this code is that the program won't write and check the registration key in one instance of the program. If I enter the correct password that matches the goodKey variable, the text file will be overwritten, but I would have to restart the program before the program recognizes that the key is right and then runs the rest of the program. The code would be perfect if I didn't have to re-run the module to get into the main program.

class registerWindow:

```
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class: Register Window')


        registerWindow=Tk()
        registerWindow.resizable(0, 0)
        registerWindowTitle=registerWindow.title('Register Your Software...')
        registerWindowSize=registerWindow.geometry('300x100')


        #Code Entry
        labelName_RegisterCode=Label(registerWindow, text='Enter Your Registration Code:')
        labelName_RegisterCode.grid(row=1, column=0)

        entryBox_RegisterCode=Entry(registerWindow, width=16, bg='red')
        entryBox_RegisterCode.grid(row=1, column=1)


        goodKey=('password')


        def registerNow(registerWindow, goodKey):
            print('Class: Register Window >> Module: Register Now')


            button_RegisterCode=Button(registerWindow, text='Submit', width=8, height=2, command=lambda: writeKey(registerWindow, goodKey))
            button_RegisterCode.place(x=220, y=50)


        def writeKey(registerWindow, goodKey):
            print('Class: Register Window >> Module: Write Key')


            text_EnteredCode=open('key.txt', 'w')
            text_EnteredCode.write(str(entryBox_RegisterCode.get()))
            text_EnteredCode.close
            keys(registerWindow, goodKey)


        def keys(registerWindow, goodKey):
            print('Class: Register Window >> Module: Keys')


            text_RegisterCodeCheck=open('key.txt', 'r')
            print(text_RegisterCodeCheck)


            if text_RegisterCodeCheck.readline() == goodKey:


                text_RegisterCodeCheck.close
                print('Your key is valid')
                registerWindow.destroy()
                mainWindowSetup()


            else:
                registerNow(registerWindow, goodKey)


        keys(registerWindow, goodKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your file may not be getting closed due to a typo in the way the close function is called .

```
text_EnteredCode.close
```

should be

```
text_EnteredCode.close()
```

This should solve the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Wow, that works! I can't believe it was something so simple! I tried taking out the commands to close the text files but  it goes back to having the same issue. Is it necessary to close the text file after each read or write?

Comment: You can do a seek() to reset the pointer to the  record after the write is completed .